# How can I search for a transaction?

Tags: ethereum-classic

I was given some crypto recently. When I try and search up the info for the transaction I'm given:

```
to: Ox5603F
Price per coin xxxx
network fee      xxx
confirmations    xxxx
date     xx/xx/xx
status   confirmed
```

But the picture looks **"Too Clean"**

How can you actually locate the transaction? When I search the info, I am given a block at a certain time in July but no transaction matches up?

Comment: What did you use to search for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Every transaction on the blockchain has a unique identifier known as a **transaction hash** (aka **tx hash**/**txn hash**).

[Coinbase describes](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/getting-started/crypto-education/what-is-a-transaction-hash-hash-id) a transaction hash as being "*similar to a receipt, that serves as proof that a transaction was validated and added to the blockchain*"

Here is an example **transaction hash**:

`0xf53015e1df3b14bdd7c3e5af1ad2c6090509c06188f35527858ae9a51e7cb254`

If you search this inside of a block explorer such as [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/), you can view the details of the transaction:

[image]

Comment: 0x5603f28e..9d8848dabb9   Is what was given to me...

Comment: Provide the entire hash or try to search it on Etherscan.io

Comment: This is all I was given, it was via a scammer

Comment: Without the entire hash, we can't confirm the validity of the transaction, considering you said it was from a scammer it's probably safe to say that it's fake.